# Can an aircraft fly without wings and stabilizers?

Tags: aerodynamics

Can there be an [aircraft](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aircraft) (not an [airplane](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airplane) like in [this other question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/do-airplanes-need-wings)) without wings and stabs (rudders and elevators)?

Comment: Very briefly...

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I don't really understand your question, do you have a picture or some reference that will show us what you're asking? [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30074/62) might help.

Comment: Unless you consider fan blades to be wings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Landing_Research_Vehicle

Comment: [This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47975/62) might be relevant too.

Comment: @fooot Aircraft are a superset of airplanes, so the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Helicopters?  Do you consider the rotor(s) to be wings?  If so, why not the turbine blades in jet engines?

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of aircraft that fly without wings and control surfaces.

[image]

[source](https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/hot-air-balloon-physics.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sure can.  Balloons do it all the time.  For a heavier than air aircraft, there a a couple of options.

Lifting body using a reaction system for stability and control.  Here the fuselage itself creates the lifting force and the aircraft would use a flight computer to control the craft and maneuver it using a reaction control system.  This can consist of thrust vectoring from the engines or separate thrusters, similar to those found on a spacecraft to control roll, pitch and yaw motion.

Another option is a pure powered lift arrangement ie a rocket belt or similar craft which can direct its lift engines to hold it aloft and to propel it forward.

Answer (score 0):

No, aircraft do not need wings or stabilizers. However, they are very desirable for takeoff and landings.

[image]

 This is an example of an unmanned aircraft without wings or stabilizer. It could just as easily be manned.

[image]
 This is another example of a manned aircraft without wings.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but those little fins are stabilizers...

Comment: The second rocket you posted (Saturn V) actually has stabilization fins at the bottom of the first stage. But there are rockets which stabilize their trajectory with vernier thrusters and engine gimbal only.

Comment: Rocket doesn't really fit the definition of aircraft.